# Why does my probability command not return an analytical answer

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

Why does my probability function return the exact same code, as opposed to an analytical/symbolic representation?

I need to get an analytical representation of the following probability function depending on a>0: *f(a)=Pr[a x1 - x2 >1 | x1 larger and x2 smaller value of two values drawn from the same standard normal distribution, a>0]*.

Plugging the condition in the `Probability[]` command and specifying an `OrderDistribution[]` for *x1* and *x2* should do the trick (see below). But instead, after some run time it returns as output the exact same code as input. How can I get the analytical/symbolic representation of my *f(a)*?

```
Probability[
 a x1 - x2 > 1, {x2, x1} \[Distributed] 
  OrderDistribution[{NormalDistribution[0, 1], 2}, {1, 2}], 
 Assumptions -> a > 0]
```

In conclusion: the problem is that the code seems fine, but that the output is not an analytical answer (some function of a) but simply a copy of the input code.

Comment: I got this to work: Probability[
 a x1 - x2 > 1, {x2 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1], 
  x1 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]}, 
 Assumptions -> {x1 > x2, a > 0}]

Comment: Hi; I agree with your comment about the assumptions. I have removed the incorrect answer hopefully someone else can help. Sorry for confusing the situation.

Comment: If you follow the approach given by @wolfies in your previous question, you'll find the answer for `a x2 - x1 < 1`.  In other words, integrate the joint probability density function of the two order statistics over the region of interest:  `a =.;
Integrate[
 Exp[-(x1^2 + x2^2)/2]/\[Pi], {x1, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {x2, 
  x1, Max[x1, (x1 + 1)/a]}, Assumptions -> a > 0]`

Comment: I've voted to re-open because the question is about `a x2 - x1 < 1` rather than `x2 - x1 < 1`.  However, as stated in my above comment, @wolfies did give an approach that will answer this slightly more general question.

Comment: The question is so similar we might see half-a-dozen such variations being asked: `a x2 - x1` or  `x2-a x1` or `x2-x1<a` ... they could all be dealt with under the umbrella of the original.

Comment: @wolfies I certainly would have hoped that the OP had shown more acknowledgement and understanding and code attempts given what you gave in the original question.  Maybe the OP opening a new question with his/her more complicated issue AND a lot of evidence of understanding of previous responses and effort would be best.